# XSL Ambiguous rule match and adjacent grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've already posted last week about a problem concerning adjacent group merge.
I'm very new and there is probably something I don't get...

So i have a template that merge adjacent groups with their CSS class names.

```
<xsl:template name="fusionElements">
<xsl:param name="classFusion" />
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]" group-adjacent="@class=$classFusion">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(node-name(.), '|', $classFusion)">
          <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
```

Then I'm calling templates like this. I'm searching `p` nodes having multiple `span`s with same CSS class.

```
<xsl:template match="p[contains(@class, 'Normal')][count(./span[contains(@class, 'USous-article')])>0]">
<xsl:call-template name="fusionElements">
  <xsl:with-param name="classFusion" select="./span[1][contains(@class,'USous-article')]/@class" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

```
<xsl:template match="p[contains(@class, 'Normal')][count(./span[contains(@class, 'UCitation')])>0]">
<xsl:call-template name="fusionElements">
  <xsl:with-param name="classFusion" select="./span[1][contains(@class,'UCitation')]/@class" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

it is working except when i have adjacent nodes with different CSS classes inside the same `p`

```
<p class="Normal">
        <a name="Art10Prg1"><!--anchor--></a>
        <span class="USous-article Default">§</span>
        <span class="USous-article Default"> </span>
        <span class="USous-article Default">1er</span>
        <span class="USous-article Default"> </span>
        <span class="USous-article Default">-</span> 
        <span class="UCitation Default">a)</span>
        <span class="UCitation Default"> </span>
Some text!</p>
```

What I'm trying to do is this  :

```
<p class="Normal">
    <a name="Art10Prg1"><!--anchor--></a>
    <span class="USous-article Default">§ 1er -</span>
    <span class="UCitation Default">a) </span>
Some text!</p>
```

I understant the error (two different templates match the same node) but I have no clues how to solve the problem.

```
Warning XTDE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /html/body[1]/div[2]/p[219] Matches both p span "UCitation" and p span "USous-article"
```

Comment: First of all, you get a warning and not an error. As for resolving it, what do you want to happen, apply one of those two templates with a higher priority? You can set a `priority` attribute one `xsl:template` e.g. `<xsl:template match="p[contains(@class, 'Normal')][count(./span[contains(@class, 'UCitation')])>0]" priority="5">`. If you do that the warning will go away and the processor only applies the template with the highest priority (instead of using the last in document order).

Comment: I tried to apply priority but it means some tags will not be merged. Thats why I'm starting to ask if my solution is really good. But I dont know how I could do without priority...

Comment: I think the approach needs to be changed to achieve that grouping, however it is a bit difficult to understand from one example and some not working code which are the rules to merge. The code in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHSZ does the right merging for your sample snippet but loses white space between `span`s and would, as currently written, also merge adjacent `span class="foo"` not containing the two classes you are looking for. I think you need to reformulate the problem and explain in more detail how flexible the code has to be and what variations the input can have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can define the various classes you want to check for as a sequence of strings and then you can use one grouping construct (at least in XSLT 3 where we have composite keys):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="classes-to-merge" as="xs:string*" select="'USous-article', 'UCitation'"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5.0"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="p[contains-token(@class, 'Normal') and span[some $class in $classes-to-merge satisfies contains-token(@class, $class)]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]" composite="yes" group-adjacent="node-name(), some $class in $classes-to-merge satisfies contains-token(@class, $class), @class">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(empty(current-grouping-key()[1])) and current-grouping-key()[2] and not(empty(current-grouping-key()[3]))">
                      <xsl:copy>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
                      </xsl:copy>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<p class="Normal">
        <a name="Art10Prg1"><!--anchor--></a>
        <span class="USous-article Default">§</span>
        <span class="USous-article Default"> </span>
        <span class="USous-article Default">1er</span>
        <span class="USous-article Default"> </span>
        <span class="USous-article Default">-</span>
        <span class="foo">foo 1</span>
        <span class="foo">foo 2</span>
        <span class="UCitation Default">a)</span>
        <span class="UCitation Default"> </span>
Some text!</p>
```

into

```
<p class="Normal"><a name="Art10Prg1">
      <!--anchor--></a><span class="USous-article Default">§ 1er -</span><span class="foo">foo 1</span><span class="foo">foo 2</span><span class="UCitation Default">a) </span>
   Some text!
</p>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHSZ/1

With XSLT 2 you can either try to use nested `for-each-group`s or you can concatenate the grouping key components to simulate a composite keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:contains-token" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="token" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tokenized-input" as="xs:string*"
            select="for $i in $input return tokenize($i, '\s+')"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="some $t in $tokenized-input satisfies $t = replace($token, '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:param name="classes-to-merge" as="xs:string*" select="'USous-article', 'UCitation'"/>

    <xsl:template match="p[mf:contains-token(@class, 'Normal') and span[some $class in $classes-to-merge satisfies mf:contains-token(@class, $class)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]" group-adjacent="concat(node-name(.), '|', some $class in $classes-to-merge satisfies mf:contains-token(@class, $class), '|', @class)">
                <xsl:variable name="grouping-keys" select="tokenize(current-grouping-key(), '\|')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$grouping-keys[1] and $grouping-keys[2] = 'true' and $grouping-keys[3]">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyyiVhq

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I want to do, it's working when I try with Saxon but unfortunately I can't use XSLT 3 in my app.

Comment: @R.BR, I have tried to transcribe the XSLT 3 approach using a composite key to XSLT 2 using a concatenated key. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your time and help. Also sorry, I usually try to do everything myself but XSL is a headache when having one week experience with it :)